# data retrieval from multiple tables using checkboxes

Tags: php

i have a database in mysql, i am using php to display the data from database to web. But as i am new in php i have a problm. i have multiple tables in my database, say 2 tables and each table represent a different theme. So, next i have to add check boxes using these 2 themes. And when i select check box should extract the value of selected theme.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="search" value="theme1_info"/> cancer &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="search" value="theme2_info"/> diabetes
<input type= "submit" value= "Search" name="sub"/>
```

what should be the action .php file?

Comment: What happen when user select both check boxes? Use radio or select elements instead.

Comment: if user select both check box then data from both tables should be come.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="GET">
        <fieldset>
                <legend>Select a theme</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="theme1" value="Name1" />Theme1 <br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="theme2" value="1" />Theme2<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="theme3" value="1" />Theme3<br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

action.php

```
<?php
    $theme1 = $_GET['theme1'];
    if($theme1 == "Name1"){
      // connect to the database
      $ThemeName = $theme1;
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "username";
      $password = "password";
      $dbname = "myDB";

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 

      $sql = "SELECT  * FROM ".$ThemeName."";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              var_dump($row);
          }
      } else {
          echo "0 results";
      }
      $conn->close();
     }

?>
```

Comment: hello Rex
thanks for your reply, but here i don't want to print any message, want to extract the data from multiple tables.

Comment: @Jyoti Sharma you can issue a database connection and select the table using mysql if the checkbox is selected..

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like this

file paths

folder/index.html
folder/action.php

index.html

```
<form method="post" aaction="action.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="search" value="theme1_info"/> cancer &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="search" value="theme2_info"/> diabetes
<input type= "submit" value= "Search" name="sub"/>

</form>
```

action.php

```
<?
if(issset($_REQUEST['theme1_info']))
{
    $theme=$_REQUEST['theme1_info'];
}else
{
$theme=$_REQUEST['theme2_info'];

}
 //you need to insert db connection

 //if your table is same as the theme name 
 $query ="SELECT * FROM '".$theme."'";


?>
```

Comment: guys i think i could not make you understand my problem
actually there are 9 tables in my database so there would be 9 check boxes. What i want is to extract the common information from these tables on the basis of selected check boxes.
for eg. if i click 2 check boxes then it should return the common among these two selected tables.
I hope This time u may be able to help. thankyou

Comment: if like so then name the checkbox with array like <input type="checkbox" name="themes[]"> then you will have all the selected themes and make the tables with theme name . concatenate the elements of checked check-box and make your query

Answer (score 0):

I have modified @Rex Adrivan code like this. `$theme1_data` and `$theme2_data` will be array of array

```
function getSelectedTheme($theme) {
    $sql = "SELECT  * FROM " . $theme . "";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $themeData = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $themeData[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $themeData;
}

if(isset($_GET['theme1_info'])){
    $theme1_data = getSelectedTheme($_GET['theme1_info']);
}
if(isset($_GET['theme2_info'])){
    $theme2_data = getSelectedTheme($_GET['theme2_info']);
}
```